# Textbox in a Combobox with Bindings

Tags: wpf

I want to display a Textbox in my combobox, for the case, that the desired value is not part of the "Info" Array.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Info}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                      SelectedValuePath="Key"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding DesiredVersion}">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Just set `IsReadOnly` to false: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.isreadonly?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Set ReadOnly to False!

```
 <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Info}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                      SelectedValuePath="Key"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding DesiredVersion}"
                      IsReadOnly="False">
        </ComboBox>
```

Hope it helped!